# What is this device?

Tags: hardware

I was doing some cleaning today and found the device below, unopened, in its original plastic bag. I'm guessing it's an accessory for a photo or video camera from the 8mm jack, but anything more than that is beyond me.

Anyone else know what it is?

Top:
[image]
Interior:
[image]
Bottom:
[image]

Comment: please remove the space between the first two slashes in the URL so it works--edit wouldn't let me fix this b/c it wants me to edit 6 or more characters.

Comment: Useful clues would include how long this has been sitting around unopened, 2 years? 5 years? 10 years? also what Canon cameras have you owned in the past? Is there a part number stamped anywhere on this? any markings besides the Canon logo?

Comment: Does the white part come out? If so, does it have any electrical contacts on it?

Comment: The TRS connector has three data lines, so this could be stereo audio, plus video.  Maybe an external storage device?  Note the weird notches in the casing, it looks like it is supposed to be mounted on something specific.  It appears that the part that runs from side to side (one end is rounded, one flat) is a lock or release of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

Aha! I found it. It's neither an audio nor a video device, but a Film Adapter Unit—a light source—for a CanoScan LiDE 700f. Misleading plug type.